# Change headers value when user inject in gatling scenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, header, gatling

I want to change headers value every time when user injected in Gatling. because I have an error in my code when code is running. error is " Signature expired: 20200124T170359Z is now earlier than 20200124T170552Z (20200124T172052Z - 15 min. ".
My code is

---

```
val signer: AwsSigner = AwsSigner(AwsCredentialsProviderWithSession, region, Service, clock)

val signedHeaders = signer.getSignedHeaders(Uri, PostMethod, queryParams, headers, emptyPayload)

 val scen =scenario("Home page").repeat(100) {

 .exec(
     http("Custom headers")
       .get("Url"+"?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=" + queryEnc)
     .headers(signedHeaders)


setUp(

   sendLoadToAws.scen.inject(rampUsersPerSec(10) to 15  during (60))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use feed, there is documentation for more informations https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder/ .

So, the first create this feed

```
val signedHeaders = {
    val signedHeaders = signer.getSignedHeaders(Uri, PostMethod, queryParams, headers, emptyPayload)

    Iterator.continually(Map(
    "header_1" -> signedHeaders.header_1,
    "header_2" -> signedHeaders.header_2
  }
```

Now need add feed for your scenario

```
.feed(signedHeaders)
   .exec(
     http("Custom headers")
       .get("url"+"?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=" + queryEnc)
```

And finaly add headers to request

```
.feed(signedHeaders)
       .exec(
         http("Custom headers")
           .get("url"+"?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=" + queryEnc)
           .header("header_name_1", "${header_1}")
           .header("header_name_2", "${header_2}")
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a suggestion on behaving my code. but this code is not working because it gives an error like.   after implement your code. Can you modify this code ?                                                   <Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/809166105827/ACP-CS-DEV-VA6-WorkerQueueService-QueueServiceTestClient is denied.</Message><Detail/></Error>

Comment: Hi your **code** is work properly but after 15 minutes the same problem is coming **Signature expired: 20200124T170359Z is now earlier than 20200124T170552Z (20200124T172052Z - 15 min. ** .  it can't refresh **signedHeaders** after execution time. because after **15 minutes** my signature will expire. so I want to refresh it before **15 minutes** .

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem in to refresh of headers value before 15 Minutes, because my code run after 15 minutes shows that **singatureDoesNotMatch or signature expired** after 15 minutes. so I did corrections in my code with the hint of [@Amerousful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7512201/amerousful). I used **Session** like

```
val scen = scenario("Home page") {
   exec(session => session.set("authroization", signedHeaders("Authorization"))
  .set("host", signedHeaders("Host"))
  .set("x-amz-date", signedHeaders("x-amz-date"))
  .set("x-amz-security-token", signedHeaders("x-amz-security-token"))

)
 .exec(
    http("Custom headers")
      .get("url + "?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=" + message)
      .header("Authorization", "${authroization}")
      .header("Host", "${host}")
      .header("x-amz-date", "${x-amz-date}")
      .header("x-amz-security-token", "${x-amz-security-token}")
    //.header("header", "${signer}")

  )

 setUp(
   scen.inject(nothingFor(5), constantUsersPerSec(80) during (3600)))
```

After running this code, the header value refreshes every time when user injects and make new **Signature**. And the **scenario** is running as your given time.